# What does the 'export' key mean in a schema definition?

Tags: 7, database

The code below is from the message module.  What does the 'export' section mean?

```
function message_schema() {
  $schema['message_type'] = array(
    'description' => 'Storage for user-defined message templates.',
    'export' => array(
      'key' => 'name',
      'identifier' => 'message_type',
      'default hook' => 'message_default_message_type',  // Function hook name.
      'primary key' => 'name',
      'api' => array(
        'owner' => 'message',
        'api' => 'message',  // Base name for api include files.
        'minimum_version' => 1,
        'current_version' => 1,
      ),
      'load callback' => 'message_type_load',
      'save callback' => 'message_type_save',
    ),
    'fields' => array(
      // Although the "name" should be enough as the primary key, the numeric ID
      // is required for the internal use of entity API.
      'id' => array(
        'type' => 'serial',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'description' => 'Primary Key: Numeric message type ID.',
      ),
      'name' => array(
        'description' => 'The unified identifier for a message type.',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
      ),
      'description' => array(
        'description' => 'Description for this message.',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('id'),
    'unique keys' => array(
      'name' => array('name'),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export` is not something that is defined in the Drupal core [Schema API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--schema.inc/group/schemaapi/7). This is most likely a convenient way to store additional data that is used internally in the module or when integrating with another custom module.

Answer (score 4):

These properties are used for implementing ctools export/import APIs.

See [How to make configuration objects exportable with CTools](http://drupal.org/node/928026).

Answer (score 1):

'export' key is for export feature provided by [ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools/) module. You can find more information from [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/928026)